# Анимация изменения фона блока

Tags: css, css-animation

Как можно сделать подобную анимацию при наведении на кнопку?

https://www.figma.com/proto/6Ag0jEYufnK9Xzm1MkkS88/Buggy?page-id=0%3A1&type=design&node-id=211-305&viewport=-2431%2C-920%2C0.24&t=XAzlx6QU7tY4lFoy-1&scaling=min-zoom&starting-point-node-id=211%3A305

Answer (score 0, accepted):

например так, добавить через псевдоэлемент и очень больной запас left и top при hover. Кнопку придется позиционировать абсолютно, не в том же блоке что и картинка и текст чтобы при ховере не перекрыть их.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.content {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 4;
}

.img {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 4;
}

button {
  display: block;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

button span {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 4;
}

button::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background: red;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: left 0.5s ease, top 0.5s ease, right 0.5s ease, bottom 0.5s ease;
}

button:hover::after {
  left: -2000px;
  top: -500px;
  right: -20px;
  bottom: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="img">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300/cccccc/E0F6FD?text=Photo-1"> коллекцию размеров и фаспечатки образцов. Lorem Ipsum не только успешно пережил без
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h3>Тур по окресностям</h3>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. В то время некий безымянный печатник создал большую коллекцию размеров и форм шрифтов, используя
      Lorem Ipsum для распечатки образцов. 
    </p>

  </div>
  <button>
  <span>Кнопка</span>
 </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли)